# How to print the numerical values in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file contains some lines of text, some with numbers only and other with text + numbers, I would like to keep only the lines that have only numbers keeping the same order of the data.

my input file

```
 35.0000    0.0250
line1
line2
table1
file
    1.0000    0.0370
line4
    2.0000   -0.0390
```

desired output file

```
   35.0000    0.0250
    1.0000    0.0370
    2.0000   -0.0390
```

Comment: Can your data include exponential numbers? How about numbers starting with `+`? Can you have lines with a number in one field and a non-number in another (e.g. `foo 17`) and if so how should those be handled? [edit] your question to include the answers to those questions.

Comment: Why is this question getting upvoted? This is a standard 'I have this problem and I want this answer' question. No effort made by OP or any attempts shown.

Answer (score 3):

similarly with `awk`

```
$  awk '!/[^0-9. -]/' file

 35.0000    0.0250
    1.0000    0.0370
    2.0000   -0.0390
```

however, to truly check numbers you should use something like this

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if($i+0==$i) {f=1; printf "%s", $i OFS} 
                    if(f) print ""; f=0}' file
```

this will normalize spacing in the lines as well.  This filters out the non numbers but keeps the numbers on the same line.

If you eliminate the line completely if there is any non number token, it can be simplified to

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0!=$i) next} $1=$1' file
```

The second script will not pass number looking tokens like `999-999-999`,  `0..10` or `2017-03-04` and accept exponential (scientific) notation or explicitly defined positive numbers `+3.00`

Comment: Right approach. To avoid adding a blank char at the end of each line is a tiny tweak: `{c=0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0==$i) printf "%s%s", (c++?OFS:""), $i; if (c) print ""}`. I changed `f` to `c` as it's now a `count` instead of just a `found` indication.

Answer (score 1):

### Big Fat Warning

This approach is not very robust, use [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42597553/1331399) if you need proper number parsing. Examples of invalid lines that **will** pass:

- `---`
- `...`
- `999-999-9999`
- `2017-03-04`

### The Answer

You do not need `sed` or `awk` for such a simple task, `grep` will suffice:

```
grep '^[0-9. \teE-]\+$' infile
```

Output:

```
 35.0000    0.0250
    1.0000    0.0370
    2.0000   -0.0390
```

#### Explanation

This expression defines a character group (`[0-9. -]`), i.e. numbers, dots, spaces and hyphens, and looks for one or more of them (`\+`). The caret (`^`) and dollar (`$`) anchor the match, so that the whole line needs to be matched.

There is a shorthand for the-whole-line-match (`-x`), so you could also go with:

```
grep -x '[0-9. \teE-]\+' infile
```

Comment: note that this will pass phone numbers `999-999-9999` or dates `2017-03-04` as well.

Comment: It'll also pass through lines of just `---` or `...` and won't allow exponential numbers (idk if the OP has them or not but why assume he doesn't?).

Comment: @EdMorton: True there is no verification of the validity of the numbers. I still think this simple approach is worth keeping, assuming the user knows that no such invalid lines are in the input, this is a more computationally efficient approach.

Comment: I disagree on it being worth keeping, this is the kind of approach that works great when tested with a specific sample input set and then comes back to bite you 6 months later when it fails cryptically and/or silently when run on your real data.

Comment: @EdMorton: I respectfully disagree, efficiency is paramount in some situations.  However, I see your point and I have added a BFW.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/\.0000/' file

 35.0000    0.0250
    1.0000    0.0370
    2.0000   -0.0390
```

Comment: very nice and simple answer

Comment: @MohsenEl-Tahawy yes it is but it's not an answer to the question you asked.

Comment: @EdMorton why do you say that? it does the job.

Comment: You said `I would like to keep only the lines that have only numbers`. This answer doesn't do that. It will keep only lines that contain `.0000` somewhere on the line so it will discard lines that only contains numbers but none of them contains `.0000` and it will print lines that contain a mixture of text plus numbers. Try it with lines like `flying monkeys XXX.0000XXX` (will incorrectly be printed) or `3.1415 555.1212` (will incorrectly be discarded).

Answer (score 0):

This lengthy `egrep` code seems to work, and allows floating point:

```
egrep  '[-+]?\b[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\b|[-+]?\b[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\b' infile
```

Output:

```
 35.0000    0.0250
    1.0000    0.0370
    2.0000   -0.0390
```

Bonus, `egrep -o` also works with the above *eregexp*, should one per line results be needed.  Output:

```
35.0000
0.0250
1.0000
0.0370
2.0000
-0.0390
```

Note: the `\b` (empty string at the edge of a word) expression considers the `-` char as *not* part of a word, so it must follow the sign check:  `[-+]?\b`.  Incorrectly using `\b[-+]?` causes the `-o` switch to not return signs.

<sub>(Code above mostly borrowed from *regular-expressions.info*'s [Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)).</sub>